# How to change the seed nodes in a cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

Consider the following scenario: a cluster consisting of 6 nodes, with 3 designated as seed nodes:

- node1: seed node
- node2: seed node
- node3: seed node
- node4: non-seed node
- node5: non-seed node
- node6: non-seed node

The objective is to alter the seed nodes from [node1, node2, node3] to [node4, node5, node6].

To achieve this, the following steps were undertaken:

1. Modify the configuration to designate nodes [node4, node5, node6] as seed nodes.
2. Restart the service on each node, one at a time.

This operation was successful, and no data loss of data during the service restarts.

However I'm not sure if this operation is ok since it doesn't mention in the documents.

Comment: It seems like you got it right. Depending on the Cassandra version, you can replace step 2 and save yourself the hassle of restarting by running instead `nodetool reloadseeds` - the command is available in Cassandra 4.0 and above.